# Need to trim leading space/ Trailing space in excel file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file with leading space into one column, I tired to remove them by using =trim() function, did not work and also tried VBA code did not work, I saw all of them as single white space but I can manually removed them but did not work via vba and trim function. Anyone has any suggestion via VBA

```
Sub RemoveLeadingSpace()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "Excel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, 
Type:=8)
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Rng.Value = VBA.LTrim(Rng.Value)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `CODE` return if you use it on the leftmost character? If your text is in `A1`, what does `=CODE(LEFT(A1, 1))` return?

Comment: Your leading space is not the ASCII space (code 32).  It is most likely the NBSP (code 160).  Change your substitute or VBA function to remove that.

Comment: Any one can correct the VBA that correct the extra leading space issue.

Comment: First of all, remove `On Error Resume Next` because that command *hides* errors, but they still occur. Second, if you just have 1 leading space, have you tried `Rng.Value = Right(Rng.Value,Len(Rng.Value)-1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Rng.Value = VBA.LTrim(Rng.Value)
```

should be

```
Rng.Value = Replace(Rng.Value,chr$(160),"")
```

if the leading space is indeed ascii 160 as [Ron Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2872922/ron-rosenfeld) suggested